# Image processing subtract two consequent frames from a continuous video using aforge

Tags: image-processing, background, aforge, subtraction, difference

I'm working on my final year project using aforge image processing.I have converted the web camera video into bitmap images.Now I want to get the difference of two consequent images that are from my web camera video.Can anyone please help me on this...

Thank you

Comment: Could you please clarify your question ?

Comment: Main thing I want is to take the difference between two frames.But these two frames are taken by the web camera continuously as a video.I want to compare the difference between each frame and put the difference into another place

Comment: see my new edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about aFrag, but simply you may find an API function that does this type of task.
or you can do it by yourself as following:

1. take two images as input , scan them pixel by pixel inside two loops
2. output is a third image whose pixel values are simply those of the first image minus the corresponding pixel values from the second image.

This [tuto](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/584141/Aforge-netplusBackgroundplusSubtraction-2fExtracti) may help you on aForg